# How to remap meta-arrow keys in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, keymap

Say I want ctrl-shift-arrows to do what meta-arrows normally do in org-mode. How do I do this?

I tried

```
(define-key org-mode-map "C-S-<up>" 'org-meta-up))
```

(and so on for down, left, and right), but then ctrl-shift-up results in this error message:

> Autoloading file /Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/org/org.elc failed to define function org-meta-up

Meta-up works correctly, but M-x org-meta-up results in the same error. What am I missing? How do I remap these org-mode keys?

This is the MacPorts version of Emacs.app; M-x version gives "GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0, NS appkit-1894.60 Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G2021)) of 2020-08-29"

Comment: I think you just have the wrong function name.  It should be `org-metaup` - without the hyphen

Comment: That was it! I am embarrassed now.

Comment: Please delete the question, in that case. (And no need to feel embarrassed.)

Comment: I'll leave the question up in case someone else tries to use these misspelled names: org-meta-up, org-meta-down, org-meta-right, org-meta-left.